# DualPane: is the first fragment refreshed when I make a transaction on fragment 2?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

I'm having a problem with the dualpane I implemented using this example: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html][1]

Here's my code for fragment 1:

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import ch.gt.ContactCall.R;

public class SideMenuFragment extends ListFragment {

private int currPosition = -1;

private String[] menuItems = new String[]{
        "Contact List",
        "Call Log",
        "Messages",
        "SMS"};


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("currChoice", currPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        //Restore last state for checked position
        currPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("currChoice", 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionMenuArrayAdapter adapter = new ActionMenuArrayAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater infl, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return infl.inflate(R.layout.sidemenu, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    //TODO: récupérer les données de la vue cliquée
    Toast.makeText(
            getActivity(),
            getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " position" + position,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    showItemDetails(position);
}

private void showItemDetails(final int index) {
    currPosition = index;

    //getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);
    DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

    if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
        details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

        // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
        // with this one inside the frame.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, details);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();

    }


}
}
```

My code for fragment 2:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import ch.gt.ContactCall.R;
import ch.gt.network.*;

import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DetailsFragment extends ListFragment {

    public int mIndex = -1;
    private UdpStreamManager gcUdpm;
    private TcpStreamManager gcTcpm;
//private boolean networkAvailable = false;

public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index){
    DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();
    f.mIndex = index;
    f.gcUdpm = new UdpStreamManager(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            1024);
    return f;
}

public int getShownIndex(){
    //return getArguments().getInt("index",0);
    return mIndex;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listitem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    //HashMap<String, String> map;

    switch (mIndex){
        //User clicked on Contact List
        case 0:
            setContactList(listitem);
            break;
        //User clicked on Call Log
        case 1:
            setCallLogs(listitem);
            break;
        //User clicked on Messages
        case 2:
            break;
        //User clicked on SMS
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            setWelcomeDisplay();
            break;
    }

}

//Fills XML with contact list
private void setContactList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listitem) {

    HashMap<String, String> map;
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "toto1");
    map.put("gcpaddress", "101");
    map.put("list_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.gc_launcher));
    listitem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "toto2");
    map.put("gcpaddress", "102");
    map.put("list_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.gc_launcher));
    listitem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "mir");
    map.put("gcpaddress", "103");
    map.put("list_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.gc_launcher));
    listitem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "CANCEL");
    map.put("gcpaddress", "");
    map.put("list_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.gc_launcher));
    listitem.add(map);

    //SimpleAdapter pout mettre les items de listitem dans le xml contacts_display
    SimpleAdapter adaptItem = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listitem, R.layout.row_layout_contactslist,
            new String[]{"img", "name", "gcpaddress"}, new int[]{R.id.list_image, R.id.name, R.id.gcpaddress});
    setListAdapter(adaptItem);

}

//Fills XML with last calls
private void setCallLogs(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listitem) {

    HashMap<String, String> map;
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "taratata");
    map.put("gcpaddress", "103");
    map.put("list_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.gc_launcher));
    listitem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "sangoku");
    map.put("gcpaddress", "106");
    map.put("list_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.gc_launcher));
    listitem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "vegeta");
    map.put("gcpaddress", "107");
    map.put("list_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.gc_launcher));
    listitem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "CANCEL");
    map.put("gcpaddress", "");
    map.put("list_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.gc_launcher));
    listitem.add(map);

    //SimpleAdapter pout mettre les items de listitem dans le xml contacts_display
    SimpleAdapter adaptItem = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listitem, R.layout.row_layout_contactslist,
            new String[]{"img", "name", "gcpaddress"}, new int[]{R.id.list_image, R.id.name, R.id.gcpaddress});
    setListAdapter(adaptItem);


}

private void setWelcomeDisplay(){

    String[] items = new String[]{""};
    WelcomeArrayAdapter welcomeAdapter = new WelcomeArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items);
    setListAdapter(welcomeAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    //Retrieve username and user address from listview
    Map<String, String> selection = (Map<String, String>) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String name = selection.get("name");

    if (name.equals("CANCEL")){
        gcUdpm.disable();
        return;
    }

    String gcpaddress = selection.get("gcpaddress");


    switch (mIndex){
        //User clicked on Contact List
        case 0:
            call();
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    "name: "+name+" address: "+gcpaddress + " position: " + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        //User clicked on Call Log
        case 1:

            break;
        //User clicked on Messages
        case 2:
            break;
        //User clicked on SMS
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.display, container, false);
}

 //Just a call test function
private void call(){
    try {
        gcUdpm.enable();
        Log.d("VR", "GcUsm enabled and socket created");
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gcUdpm.startReceive();
    gcUdpm.startStreaming();
}

}
```

And my xml for the hover handling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Handles color change on button selection-->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/selected" />
</selector>
```

Which is used in each item of the listview.

The dualpane I'm implementing is different because I'm not loading text but another list through another listfragment who's updating its view using a SimpleAdapter object.
This concerns only the background color of my first listfragment when I select an item, it's ok when I don't update the second fragment on the onListItemClick event, the selected item remains in grey when the others keep their normal background in black.
Then when I call the method which loads the details in the other listfragment (actually It doesn't load only text but a list of users), the selected item changes its background color but only for a few millisecs before the other fragment changes its content.
I'm not quite sure of what is happening but I have the feeling that the whole view of the activity is updated when I change a fragment's content.

So my questions are: am I right about this behavior and how to avoid it?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not elegant but I handled it that way:
In fact everything comes from the adapters I'm creating on every screen refresh, so you have to implement callbacks functions for your Fragments to communicate the selected position to the parent activity, once done, you memorize the last item selected before assigning the new selected position on the next click, so you get the actual position and the last position.
Back to your custom ArrayAdapter, in your overridden getView method, you have only to get the parent context in your constructor and get this values from there and finally change the background color of the concerned items (the selected to the new color and the last selected to original background.

And like Tony Stark would say: I'm a genious. :P